# How can I turn page the change animation off in VuePress?

Tags: vuepress

The VuePress default theme and also other themes have an animation / transition between page changes:

https://vuepress-theme-hope.github.io/guide/get-started/intro/

How can I turn that *** off ?

I found some documentation about some "Switch Animation" but that does not explain anything:

https://vuepress-theme-hope.github.io/guide/layout/